# Is there a name for the following property in the theory of topological spaces?

Tags: general-topology, terminology

I worked out the following lines. Probably it is totally trivial, but maybe this is interesting in the theory of topological/metric spaces.

Let $\Omega$ be an open subset of the Euclidean $n$-space. Equip $\Omega$ with the subspace topology inherited from $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Let $V$ be a compact subspace of $\Omega$. Define for each point $x\in V$, $$R(x)=\sup\{r>0:B(x,r)\subset \Omega\}$$
where $B(x,r)$ denote the open ball of radius $r$ with center $x$. Note that $$B(y,R(x)-d(x,y))\subset B(x,R(x))\subset \Omega.$$ So $|R(y)-R(x)|\le d(x,y)$. Therefore $R$ is a continuous function on $V$. Moreover, $R>0$ and $V$ is compact, so $\rho:=\min R(V)>0$. Let $W=\bigcup\limits_{x\in V}\overline{B(x,\rho/2)}$.

Given a sequence $(z_n)_n$ in $W$, for each $n$, $z_n=x_n+y_n$ for some $x_n\in V$ and $y_n\in\overline{B(x,\rho/2)}$. Since $V$ and $\overline{B(x,\rho/2)}$ are both sequentially compact, there is a subsequence $x_{n_k}\rightarrow x\in V$ and $y_{n_k}\rightarrow y\in \overline{B(x,\rho/2)}$ as $k\rightarrow\infty$. Then $z_{n_k}\rightarrow x+y\in W$. So $W$ is closed. $W$ is clearly bounded. So $W$ is compact.

Therefore, with the assumption in the first paragraph, any compact subset of $\Omega$ can be strictly contained in another compact subset. Is there a special name for such a property in a general topological space? Moreover, the larger compact subset contains neighorhoods of uniformly large diameter of the points in the smaller compact subset. Is there a special name for this property in the theory of metric spaces?

Comment: Sounds a bit like $T_4$ (normal)...?

Comment: I think it's implied by $T_4$, but I'm having trouble seeing that the neighbourhood of the inner compact set we are guaranteed can be chosen to be precompact.

Comment: Maybe the "closest" well-known property of a general topological space is local compactness.